# How to present Powerpoint presentation in xpages?

Tags: xpages, powerpoint

I've searched and found posts about Powerpoint but not in xpages.  Can someone direct me how I program my powerpoint presentation in xpages?  Each of the slides has navigation to another slide depending on what they click on the previous slide so that functionality would need to be included.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for code to create a Powerpoint presentation or display? The latter may be challenging to do in a browser, but the former is possible.

Comment: I already have a PP presentation that has a manual flow with links to other slides on each slide depending on how you answer questions or simply want to go to the next slide.  I need to program this or use the actual presentation in xpages/Notes, if possible.  Do I need to use pages with hyperlinks or does xpages have something to do this or forms with embedded/computed pages?  Looking for the easiest way and yes, it's for the web.